# Arrow above text (like widehat)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows

I'm doing a presentation for a lay audience and I was hoping to have an arrow above the word "dim" to differentiate the dimension vector from the dimension generally. However, `$\xrightarrow{dim}$` puts the arrow in the centre (as one would have for a map) which makes the dim small and doesn't look good. So is there an arrow which works like a `$\widehat{dim}$` but with an arrow instead of a hat?

P.S. The text I'm using just uses an underline but I feel it isn't noticeable enough. Likewise I could just use the hat perhaps but I think an arrow is more intuitive (it was how we denoted vectors at my highschool). However, I will also accept other ways of differentiating.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use `\overrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
 \overrightarrow{\dim} , \quad \overrightarrow{\text{dimension}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: dim with extensible arrow above]

This and further alternatives can be found at the [LaTeX-Community forum](http://latex-community.org/forum/) in the topic [Extended Vector Arrow](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=22999). So there are nice arrows with `esvect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
\[
 \vv{\dim} , \quad \vv{\text{dimension}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: esvect example]